# Re-levelling in R for a xtab based on a condition

Tags: r

For a sample dataframe:

```
df <- structure(list(region = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
                                          2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), class = "factor"), 
                     result = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), weight = c(0.126, 
                                                                                        0.5, 0.8, 1.5, 5.3, 2.2, 3.2, 1.1, 0.1, 1.3, 2.5)), .Names = c("region", 
                                                                                                                                                       "result", "weight"), row.names = c(NA, 11L), class = "data.frame")
```

I draw a cross tabulation using:

```
df$region <- factor(df$region)
result <- xtabs(weight ~ region + result, data=df)
result
```

However I want to ensure the regions of the xtab are in order of magnitude of percentage 1s in sample.  (i.e. 1s represent 29% of region a and 33% of region b).  Therefore I would like the xtab to be reordered, so region b is first, then a.

I know I could use relevel, however this would be dependent on me looking at the result and re-levelling where appropriate.

Instead I want this to be automatic in the code and not dependent on the user (as this code will be running lots of times, and completing further analysis on the resulting xtab).

If anyone has any ideas, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reorder the xtab on the values of the second column using `order` as follows:

```
result[order(result[, 2], decreasing=T),]
```

`order` ranks the values, adding decreasing=T ranks from top to bottom.