# Ordering xtab BY proportion in R

Tags: r

For a sample dataframe:

```
df <- structure(list(region = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
                                          2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), class = "factor"), 
                     result = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), weight = c(0.126, 
                                                                                        0.5, 0.8, 1.5, 5.3, 2.2, 3.2, 1.1, 0.1, 1.3, 2.5)), .Names = c("region", 
                                                                                                                                                       "result", "weight"), row.names = c(NA, 11L), class = "data.frame")


df$region <- factor(df$region)
result <- xtabs(weight ~ region + result, data=df)
result
```

I want to reorder the 1s of the result column.  As I understand it ([from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37389791/re-levelling-in-r-for-a-xtab-based-on-a-condition)), I could use order:

```
result <- result[order(result[, 2], decreasing=T),]
result
      result
region   0     1
     b 6.9 3.500
     a 5.8 2.426
```

HOWEVER this appears to be just ordering by the number of 1s - I want instead to use the proportion of 1s in each region (i.e. percentage).  How can I use order (or something else) to develop my xtab the way I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `prop.table`:

```
result[order(prop.table(result,1)[,2], decreasing=TRUE),]
#      result
#region   0     1
#     b 6.9 3.500
#     a 5.8 2.426
```

Where `prop.table(result,1)` gives:

```
prop.table(result,1)
#      result
#region         0         1
#     a 0.7050814 0.2949186
#     b 0.6634615 0.3365385
```

Comment: @thelatemail - obviously not explained clearly by myself, but that's perfect.  Thank you.